# Rsync copied binary files still differ?

Tags: linux

I copied some FLV video files to my Android sdcard with `rsync`, but later found that *some* of these videos were unplayable (halted after some number of seconds of playing). Upon further examination, `diff` tells me that the files are not the same, as does `cmp`, indicating a discrepancy around byte 4M on a 7M file.

Trying to use rsync again does not change this, but a simple `cp` does.

(For full disclosure, I do get errors with rsync if I use the -a flag because it can't change the group, but I don't think this is related, in part because the error occurs even on "good" files.)

What's going on?

Comment: Did you try to use rsync with checksums (`-c`), instead of only checking for timestamps?

Answer (score 0):

This should definitely not be happening. You could also try adding the flags `--stats --progress` to the command and see if the files are actually updated.